# Do You Have to Virtualize Wrapper Functions?

Tags: c++, class, wrapper, virtual

Suppose I have a class BST and a child class RBT. The class BST has a wrapper function as follows:

```
void BST::walk(ostream& to)
{
    inorder_walk(root, to);
}
```

Where `inorder_walk` is a virtual function. When I have a new virtualized `inorder_walk` function in my RBT class, do I need to make `walk` virtual as well, even though in both classes all `walk` needs to do is call `inorder_walk`? That is, although the `walk` function isn't virtual, when it calls a virtual function inside of it, does C++ know to call the virtualized function? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Describing code is rarely successful. Please put a [mre] in your question.

Comment: Is `inorder_walk()` really a `BST::inorder_walk()` ? Or does it belong to a parent class `DataStructure` that `BST` inherits from, which holds the original virtual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to make it virtual.

Comment: @simon Because virtual dispatch is virtual dispatch.  I could write a few pages on what polymorphism and virtual dispatch does and how it works.  Or I could find you a pointer to a SO post on the subject.